# How to write dates (MM/DD/YY) into a matrix (SAS)

Tags: matrix, sas

I have following problem:

I need to write a begin and end date into a matrix. Where the matrix contains the yearly quarters (1-4) in the collumns and the rows are the year.

E.g.

Matrix:

```
Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 
            2010
            2011
```

Now the Date **01.01.2010** should be put in the first element and the date **09.20.2011** in the sixed element.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide the code you tried. As is, the question is not very clear. Are you working in a data step or what? Are the dates contained in dataset variables or where?

Comment: So Far I dont have any code, since I couldn't find out how to write already existing data points into a matrix. So Far I am using arrays.                          The dates are variables in data format and I use a data step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to consider that SAS does not actually have date/time/datetime variables. It just uses numeric variables formatted as date/time/datetime. The actual value being:

- days since 1/1/1960 for dates
- seconds since 00:00 for times
- seconds since 1/1/1960 00:00 for datetimes

SAS does not even distinguish between integer and float numeric types. So a date value can contain a fractional part.

What you do or can do with a SAS numeric variable is completely up to you, and mostly depends on the format you apply. You could mistakenly format a variable containing a date value with a datetime format... or even with a currency format... SAS won't notice or complain.

You also have to consider that SAS does not even actually have matrixes and arrays. It does provide a way to simulate their use to read and write to dataset variables.

That said, SAS does provide a whole lot of formats and informats that allow you to implement date and time manipulation.

Assuming you are coding within a data step, and assuming the "dates" are in dataset numeric variables, then the PUT function can extract the datepart you need to calculate row, column of the matrix element to write to, like so:

```
DATA table;
   ARRAY dm{2,4} dm_r1c1-dm_r1c4 dm_r2c1-dm_r2c4;
   beg_row = PUT(beg_date, YEAR4.)-2009;
   end_row = PUT(end_date, YEAR4.)-2009;
   beg_col = PUT(beg_date, QTR1.);
   end_col = PUT(end_date, QTR1.);
   dm{beg_row,beg_col} = beg_date;
   dm{end_row,end_col} = end_date;
RUN;
```

... or if you are using a one-dimensional array:

```
DATA table;
   ARRAY da{8} da_1-da_8;
   beg_index = 4 * (PUT(beg_date, YEAR4.)-2010) + PUT(beg_date, QTR1.);
   end_index = 4 * (PUT(end_date, YEAR4.)-2010) + PUT(end_date, QTR1.);
   da{beg_index} = beg_date;
   da{end_index} = end_date;
RUN;
```

Comment: It's 01/01/1960 in SAS, 1970 is unix. Also, dates are integers, there is no fractional part. Datetime values are expressed in seconds since `'01JAN1960:00:00'dt`, and time values are expressed in seconds since `'00:00't`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Although the statement "dates are integers" is a bit useless in a language where there is no true date type and no true integer type. You can store date and time values in a numeric variable using the fractional part as the time part. Numeric variables are all float. 86400 is your friend here, if you know what you are doing :)

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by 'using the fractional part as the time part'. The only use of a 'fractional part' in SAS date, time and datetime values is for storage of *parts* of seconds, there is no relevance for dates. My statement 'dates are integers' merely means that any fractional part of the number is ignored if the value is displayed using date formats.

Comment: Technically, SAS does allow for the possibility of time stored as fractional part of date.  It won't display it properly, but there are some circumstances where it occurs (other DBMSs mostly), and you can use `DHMS()` to arrive at the real datetime.  But generally, you are correct, you would not usually do this intentionally in SAS, and it probably shouldn't be in the answer as it's more likely to confuse someone than be helpful.